# How to continue calling getjson untill it has no empty response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, getjson

Hi all i got a getjson call and wondering how i can check its response(siteContents) if it is empty or if it doesn't have a required string(for example look for seasonEpisode=)then call getjson again .Can we call getjson itself from within it ?My goal is to get correct response from getjson.Hope you guys help me.Thanks

```
$.getJSON('http://www.mysite.com/doit.php?value=55?', function(data){
    //$('#output').html(data.contents);

 var siteContents = data.contents;
```

Comment: Does calling the same exact url return different results?  Doesn't sound very RESTful

Comment: Thanks for reply. Sometime calling that php url comes with empty response or getjson doesnt finish at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var handler = function(data){
   //$('#output').html(data.contents);
   var siteContents = data.contents; 
   if (!siteContents) { 
       $.getJSON('http:/...', handler);
       return;
   }
   // handle siteContents
}

$.getJSON('http://...', handler);
```

---

edit: the above would spam the server with repeating attempts in case the siteContents is empty - creating infinite loop and high load. I would suggest two improvements:

1) count how many repeating empty siteContents loops you made. Cancel the loop with an error message (if appropriate) after some failure threshold (eg. 20 attempts).

2) do the iteration with `setTimeout(function() { $.getJSON(...) },  delay)`  where delay is some milliseconds to wait between retries.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the better question is why doesn't your server return the 'correct' response on the first try? Or as NuclearGhost points out, why does it return different responses for the same request?

But to accomplish what you're asking for requires recursion. You can't just do it in a loop because the response is asynchronous. But if you name a function, you can call that function in the success handler, something like this:

```
function getJSONRecursive(maxRetries, count) {
    if(!count) count = 1;
    if (count > maxRetries) {
        alert('Giving up after '+count+' retries.');
        return;
    }
    $.getJSON('http://www.mysite.com/doit.php?', function(data) {
        if(!data || !data.contents || data.contents.indexOf('seasonEpisode') == -1) {
            getJSONRecursive(++count, maxRetries);
        } else  {
            $('#output').html(data.contents);
        }
    })
}
```

Then invoke it like this:

```
getJSONRecursive(5);
```

I wouldn't recommend doing without the count, because otherwise you will overflow the stack if the correct response never comes back. If the situation you're avoiding is a server timeout or overload problem, then I would recommend putting the recursive call in a timeout, like so:

```
if(!data || !data.contents || data.contents.indexOf('seasonEpisode') == -1) {
    setTimeout(function() { getJSONRecursive(++count, maxRetries)}, 5000);
    // etc.
```

This waits an extra 5 seconds between calls, but the extra time will help ensure your server doesn't get slammed and your getjson calls don't just run themselves out too quickly.

Comment: when passing to setTimeout wrap the getJSONRecursive in an annoymous function or else you are calling it and passing the return value to setTimeout...

Comment: Ah, [right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout), my bad. Fixed.